# как разрешить доступ к PUT DELETE в RESTfull yii2

Tags: php, yii2, angularjs, rest

Как разрешить доступ к `PUT DELETE` в *RESTfull yii2* ?
Использую *angularjs*.

Answer (score 1):

В Yii2 по умолчанию уже есть поддержка всех методов REST API, для этого достаточно наследовать свой контроллер от контроллера `\yii\rest\ActiveController`.

Приведу на примере пользователей:

```
namespace app\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class UserController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\User';
}
```

Потом в конфигурации прописать в `urlManager` следующие правила:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'user'],
    ],
]
```

И тогда у вас доступны все методы REST API:

- `GET /users`: постраничный вывод всех пользователей;
- `HEAD /users`: общий вывод информации о пользователях;
- `POST /users`: создание пользователя;
- `GET /users/123`: возвращает данные о пользователе 123;
- `HEAD /users/123`: вовзращает общую информацию о пользователе 123;
- `PATCH /users/123` и `PUT /users/123`: обновляет пользователя 123;
- `DELETE /users/123`: удаляет пользователя 123;
- `OPTIONS /users`: показывает поддерживаемые методы относительно `/users`;
- `OPTIONS /users/123`: показывает поддерживаемые методы относительно `/users/123`.

Это всё и более детально описано в [гайде](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html), правда на английском.